Filtering on sets of sets
I am working with sets of sets, where the internal sets are representation of objects, i.e. the elements of internal sets are pairs of the form (attribute, value).
In a simplified, toy example, I have two attributes, make (with three values) and engine (with two values). Given a set of such 'objects', D (say a car dealer inventory), I would like to be able to filter the set of the makes that have a V6 engine.
All I have managed so far is to return the subset of D that has V6, in the form of the v6s. This, obviously, gives me a set of sets of pairs {(toyota, v6), (chevy, v6)}.
How I filter this one further? I need some sort of
v6make :: "pair set" where "v6make = ???"
that will return {toyota, chevy}
type_synonym pair = "nat × nat"

definition make :: nat where "make = 1"
definition engine :: nat where "engine = 2"

definition toyota :: pair where "toyota = (make, 1)"
definition ford :: pair where "ford = (make, 2)"
definition chevy :: pair where "chevy = (make, 3)"

definition v4 :: pair where "v4 = (engine, 4)"
definition v6 :: pair where "v6 = (engine, 6)"

definition D :: "pair set set" where 
  "D = {{toyota, v6}, {ford, v4}, {chevy, v4}, {chevy, v6}}"

definition v4s :: "pair set set" where "v4s = Set.filter (λx. v4 ∈ x) D"
definition v6s :: "pair set set" where "v6s = Set.filter (λx. v6 ∈ x) D"



I found out one solution :D
definition v4make :: "pair set" where 
  "v4make = Set.filter (λx. fst x = make) (⋃{x. x ∈ v4s})"

Is there a better one?
